# Firebase debug view with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, firebase-analytics

I am trying to use Firebase in my React native app, which I am developing using the Expo managed workflow.

I have installed both `expo-firebase-analytics` and `firebase` npm packages. As per the documentation, Firebase will not work in the Expo client and only when the app is built and working on a real device.

To make it work on the Expo client, following the instructions, I have created a web app on Firebase and taken the `apiKey` as well as the `measurementId`, which I have included in my app.json file.

```
"web": {
  "config": {
    "firebase": {
      "appId": "1:xxxxxxxxxx66e",
      "apiKey": "AIxxxxxxxxxxv0",
      "measurementId": "G-XXXXXXXX"
    }
  }
}
```

I have also called these two functions from the `expo-firebase-analytics` package in my App.js file:

```
Analytics.setUnavailabilityLogging(false);
Analytics.setDebugModeEnabled(true);
```

All of my firebase events and logs are being logged to the console. However, I can't see any data in 'Debug View' on the Firebase console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. Everything seems to be configured well according to documentation and I get no error, and every event is logged to console. But nothing appears in debug view.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any update?